# Kendo UI Grid Toolbox Commands (Create, Save, Update) To enable Conditionally

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a simple Kendo UI Grid.  The gird is in batch mode and works fine.  I am using Web API to bind the actual CRUD methods.

I have to show hide the Toolbar Buttons conditionally.  How and Where (which event) can I create this kind of functionality

For example:

```
If(user.Role.Permission == "Edit"){
   //Show Edit Button else hide
}
```

Here is the Actual Kendo UI Grid Code

```
var baseUrl = "/api/TicketType";
 var datatype = "json";
 var contentType = "application/json";

 var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                autoSync: false,
                batch: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: baseUrl,
                        dataType: datatype,
                        contentType: contentType
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: baseUrl,
                        dataType: datatype,
                        contentType: contentType,
                        type: "POST"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: baseUrl,
                        dataType: datatype,
                        contentType: contentType,
                        type: "PUT"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && data.models) {
                            return kendo.stringify(data.models);
                        }
                        else {
                            return {
                                take: data.take,
                                skip: data.skip,
                                pageSize: data.pageSize,
                                page: data.page
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "data.$values",
                    total: "recordCount",
                    model: {
                        id: "TypeID",
                        fields: {
                            TypeID: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                            TypeCode: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                            Description: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } }                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: datasource,
                toolbar: [
                    {name: "create", text: "Add New Record"},
                    { name: "save", text: "Save Changes" },
                    { name: "cancel", text: "Cancel Changes" },
                ],
                columns:
                [
                    { field: "TypeID", width: 50, title: "ID"},
                    { field: "TypeCode", width: 150, title: "Code"},
                    { field: "TypeDescription", width: 200, title: "Description"}
                ]

            })

            datasource.read(); // This will bind to the grid.
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    hidetoolbar();
});

function onDataBound(arg) {
    hidetoolbar();
}

function onDataBinding(arg) {
    hidetoolbar();
}


function hidetoolbar(){
    If(user.Role.Permission != "Edit"){
        $("#Grid .k-add").parent().hide(); 
        $("#Grid .k-update").parent().hide();
        $("#Grid .k-cancel").parent().hide();
        //OR
        $("#Grid .k-add").parent().remove(); 
        $("#Grid .k-update").parent().remove();
        $("#Grid .k-cancel").parent().remove();
    }
}

 $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: datasource,
    dataBound: onDataBound, // Added
    dataBinding: onDataBinding, //Added
    toolbar: [
        {name: "create", text: "Add New Record"},
        { name: "save", text: "Save Changes" },
        { name: "cancel", text: "Cancel Changes" },
    ],
    columns:
    [
        { field: "TypeID", width: 50, title: "ID"},
        { field: "TypeCode", width: 150, title: "Code"},
        { field: "TypeDescription", width: 200, title: "Description"}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show or hide the toolbar button, you will need to implement the logic in the Databound event of the Grid.

Please see the below example:
[JSBin Databound example](http://jsbin.com/fogulena/3/edit)

Note: Your question is a duplicate of [Make Command Button invisible in Kendo Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664064/make-command-button-invisible-in-kendo-grid).